# Calculating $a_n$ in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin(\frac{n \pi}{2})=T_0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I'm looking to solve the following when $T_0$ is a constant:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right)=T_0$$

If it matters this was reached from the following:

$$T(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{2d}\right)e^{\frac{-n^2\pi^2k^2t}{4d^2}}$$
$$T(d,0)=T_0$$

Comment: Well, you could let $a_1 = T_0$ and the rest of the $a_n = 0$. However, I would double check that the expression you have for $T(x,t)$ is correct.

Comment: I'm guessing you are solving the heat equation with some given boundary condition? For this you would need $T(x,0)$ for all $x$ (in $[0,d]$) for it to give a unique solution.

Comment: The problem as stated has infinitely many solutions.  As such, it is dubious that it is a legitimate problem.

Comment: @Dr.MV it has been suggested that I make a piece-wise solution to $a_n$. The proposed solution is broken up by the odd/even nature of $n$.

Comment: @NickChapman For $n$ even, $\sin (n\pi/2)=0$.  How does decomposing into even and odd series work then?

Comment: @NickChapman  Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Did you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{2}\right)=T_0$$ instead?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis no, I posted what I intended to. It just appears that the information given that led to this point was not accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original problem that was posted has no unique solution.

For example, letting $a_1=T_0$ and $a_n=0$ for $n\ne 1$ provides one solution.  Letting $a_3=-T_0$ and $a_n=0$ for $n\ne 3$  provides another.  There are an infinite number of possible solutions.

Thus, either there isn't a unique one or the problem is mis-stated.

If it has been mis-stated, then let's start by assuming that

$$T(x,0) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \sin(n\pi x/2d)$$

Now, let's see how we can arrive at an answer.

To that end, multiply both sides of the equation by $\sin(m\pi x/2d)$ and integrate from $0$ to $2d$.

$$\int_0^{2d} \sin(m\pi x/2d) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \sin(n\pi x/2d) dx=T_0\int_0^{2} \sin(m\pi x/2d)  dx$$

Formally, interchange the order of integration and summation and exploit the orthogonality of ${\sin (n\pi x/2d)}$ on $0\le x\le 2d$ to reveal that

$$a_m=(T_0/d)\int_0^{2d} \sin(m\pi x/2d)  dx=T_0 \frac{1-(-1)^m}{(m\pi/2)}$$

Comment: OP does not say that $T(x,0) = T_0$ he says that $T(d,0) = T_0$ (which is not enough information to give a unique solution but anyway thats what is written).

Comment: Instead of guessing that OP meant something else (this seems just like a wild guess - it really seems like OP is trying to ask the question as it is written.) I think it's better to get OP to clarify or answer the question as given.

Comment: @Winther Thank you for sharing your opinion.  It is likely that this question pertains to a boundary value problem that was solved by using separation of variables.  The initial condition of a well-posed problem would be in the form $T(x,0)=f(x)$.  That is the assumption here.

Comment: @Dr.MV the condition $T(d,0)=T_0$ is correct. Optimize your solution rather than the problem.

Comment: @NickChapman The problem that was posted has no unique solution.  $a_1=T_0$ and $a_n=0$ for $n>1$ is one.  $a_3=-T_0$ and $a_n=0$ for $n\ne 3$  is another.  And so on.  What answer do you seek, because either there isn't a unique one or the problem is mis-stated.